# Is it "iterate through" or "iterate over" something?

Tags: terminology, iteration

Just thought about it. Is there a semantic distinction, or are we free to choose?

**EDIT** I accepted [@roygbivs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715388/is-it-iterate-through-or-iterate-over-something/2715452#2715452), because most of the answers suggested that it is a matter of taste which one to choose, and that it doesn't really change the meaning. In that case, since the *through* and the *over* don't carry any information at all (in that particular context), they can be left out.

Comment: I'd say "iterate through", but English isn't my first language.

Comment: It is neither `through` or `over`. Both are useless adverbs. You would simply say `iterate`. `I am writing code to iterate the collection.`  Otherwise, it's like stating the meaning of iterate twice.

Comment: Prepositions are not useless decorators in general.  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23023/373969

Answer (score 82, accepted):

"through" and "over" are useless adverbs.

Examples:

- > While iterating this collection, my code throws an error.
- > This code iterates the collection.
- > Your assignment is to write code that iterates the collection.

It's like saying "up north" or "down south". "up" and "down" are useless.  Instead you should say, "I am going north for the summer." or "In the south, they grow cotton."

Comment: I feel like they're more prepositions than they are adverbs, but the definitions for either seem flexible and it depends on how you parse the sentence. Is it a phrasal verb that you're simplifying? Iterate over => iterate? Or do you iterate as an intransitive verb with a preposition, which then simplifies to a transitive verb?

Comment: As Mark has noted, "through" and "over" are prepositions. How would you say it, then? Do you simply "iterate the container"? That doesn't sound right at all to me.

Comment: @Michael, it may not sound correct because we (collectively) use iterate in conjunction with *through* or *over*. Roy gives a good example with the *up* & *down* with direction. I have used *iterate the list/controls* and, after a while, it felt more natural and less cluttered with useless words.

Comment: To me, _iterating something_ means _repeating it_; it does not sound right as a synonym for _looping_ over it. On the other hand, _iterate over_ or _through_ are commonly used in this sense.

Comment: Indeed,  the example sentences in this answer mean repeating the collection, which is not the intended meaning, even if grammatically correct.  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23023/373969

Answer (score 57):

Not right or wrong, just some stats:

```
= term =           = Google =   = Github =
"iterate over"      1,440,000   10,569,846 search results
"iterate through"     908,000    5,605,973
"iterate thru"         44,200      141,982
——————————————————————————————————————————
"iterate on"          402,000      187,576
"iterate in"           63,300      117,962
"iterate across"       10,900      208,342
"iterate within"        8,470       14,577
"iterate along"         8,060        6,396
"iterate among"         5,970        2,960
"iterate against"       2,580        3,255
"iterate inside"        2,450       35,060
"iterate amongst"         406       22,274
"iterate amidst"           66            0
```

<sub>Google stats updated on 4/25/2018. Subsequent searches show that results are unstable.

Github stats updated on 4/25/2018. Only code occurrences are counted.</sub>

Comment: Interesting answer, I did not know that Google provides this such nice report, how to search on google like this?

Comment: @LucasPires This is manually assembled 

Answer (score 19):

I think it depends on the object of the preposition; you iterate over the iterator, over the collection, over the container, over the list, over the range, etc. but you iterate through (the contents of) the list, through (the elements of) the container, through the (elements of ) the range, through (the elements of) the collection, etc. In almost all cases they are interchangeable; the only place I would use "over" but not "through" is with respect to the iterator, itself; but for any iterable object, I'd use either "over" or "through".

Comment: This distinction sounds the best. By the way, ''over'' sounds more superficial, like you're an outside consumer. But ''through'' sounds more personal, more intimate. Like maybe you're the implementer and you're writing the enumerator.

Comment: I have no problems (as a native English speaker) iterating over a list, range or collection. In fact, "iterate through" **always** sounds wrong to my ear. @Mark, iterating is by definition external. So over is always best.

Comment: @jmucchiello, I believe we have a misunderstanding; note that I wrote "iterate over the range" and "through (the elements of) the range". I agree that over sounds more natural, but I think that "through" sounds ok in most cases, except for the iterator, itself, in which case "through" sounds much more awkard than "over".

Comment: I think Mark said it right. Over is outside and Through sounds inside. My problem is I don't think the iterator is ever inside and thus never think through is right, even in your instance Michael. If I have a list of cars, I will iterator over the list of cars. I would not say "I iterate through the cars of the container." or through the car elements of the container. or through the range of cars in the container. None of those sound good.

Answer (score 16):

I would say iterate over, and this is the way I've always seen it written.

Comment: However, in Google, “iterate through the collection” yields significantly more results than both “over” and without a preposition...

Answer (score 7):

Both essentially mean the same!

So, you are free to choose whichever suits you.

Answer (score 3):

I would always say "iterate **over**" because it emphasizes the (relatively important) fact that the iterators themselves are not contained in the container that is the subject of the iteration.

To say "iterate through", to me, would imply that one were looking at each element of the container in turn, which is not really what is happening.

In contrast, saying "iterate over" implies to me that one is receiving an external handle to each element of the container in turn, which *is* really what is happening.

However, there's nothing *wrong* with "iterate through", and anyone who understands iterators would surely understand both phrases.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's probably just "iterate" period. But its obvious what you mean in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I use "loop over". Simple.

Answer (score 1):

The summary text for System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() says:

> Returns an enumerator that
>   iterates **through** the collection.

Personally I say through ... but really I don't think it matters which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

The important word is iterate, what filler you place with it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I picture "iterating through" something, the way I do a file cabinet. Maybe it's just personal preference though, given my mental image - I think "Iterate Over" is the more common usage.

Answer (score 0):

I use both at random, sometimes in the same sentence. Dropping the connecting word is bad grammar and neither is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary says "iterate" is a transitive verb meaning to "say or do again; repeat".

Would you "repeat over" something you just said, or "repeat through" it?  I think you'd just plain repeat it.  Or just plain iterate it, as you prefer.

Having said that, if you're using "iterate" as some kind of synonym for "loop"... looping through data one iteration at a time, perhaps, then maybe you ARE "iterating through".  This is a minefield!

Answer (score 0):

I think they are interchangeable for most practical purposes, but in my comments I personally tend to use them with a small distinction: I interpret to "iterate over" something to be similar to the sense that you would say "I'll look over it". That is, it's not a deep inspection: you are browsing over it looking for something. Conversely, to "iterate through" is to go through each and every one purposefully.

So if I was just searching for one item in a list I would say I was "iterating over" the list.....if I was applying some transformation to each item, it would be "iterate through".

Answer (score 0):

Either is a rhetoical [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28rhetoric%29).  You should remove the superfluous preposition.  As in

> "This loop iterates the top 10 products"

or, perhaps

> "I am iterating the answers looking for the one to accept"

Comment: +1 for simply stating it's a tautology.. which i was about to add. rather than that long "it's a useless adverb" :D

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp's LOOP macro uses `for element in list`, but `for element across array` (it's different so the compiler can generate more efficient code ... yeah, it's weird), suggesting that the preposition isn't really that important.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way.

```
J's members are dissimilar, but all can be incremented.
Having incremented every member of 'J' ...
J contains incrementable elements.
J refers to several items.
J refrances several items.
Everything in J is incrementable.
Everything J refers to should necessarily be thought of as being storable in a set.
Sequentially referring to J's contents ...
Apply between each element of J and R until all possible compatible pairs have been found.
Ask J using it's 'ask' function to sequentially apply addition between it's contents and return the result.
```

It's like the word "has", that can so often reduce a whole sentance to a single word.

Why not keep iterate for iteration, like this -> circle, triangle, octagon, pentagon, hexagon.